# How to change the default image viewer in SimpleITK

Tags: image-processing, itk

I am using the SImpleITK and ipython notebook for image processing and as we know imagej is the default image viewer in simpleitk. But the type of image i am using is .mha and .mha is not supported by imagej. For this I have to use fiji or imagej2.

I have tried to make fiji as a default image viewer according to the instruction mentioned in simpleitk FAQs but did not get success and show the following message: [image: Make Fiji as default Image viewer in SimpleITK]

I want to know what mistake I am doing .

**How to make Fiji or imagej2 as a default image viewer for all types of images when I work  with simpleitk and ipython notebook.**

Thanks.

Comment: Your command to set the environment variable is wrong. Take a closer look at the FAQ. There should be an `=` after the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you still have ImageJ in your STIK_SHOW_COMMAND variable which is not found in your fiji folder.
Read the instructions again. I assume you did not follow them well enough. Your variable should contain the new image viewer and no ImageJ in a different folder.

Comment: ImageJ is the default viewer which does not support .mha files. but imagej2 or fiji support it. And we know that "fiji is nothing but imagej" that's why it looks like imagej. So I have read the instruction many times and I also have tried many times but did not get success. so question still remains same I want to make fiji as a default viewer not imagej..Can you suggest proper steps..

Comment: But the Fiji-Executable is not named ImageJ-Linux64 but Fiji-Linux or Fiji-Linux64. At least the Fiji documentation says so. So whatever you read, you did not understand or the Fiji doc is wrong. Your computer is trying to execute a file named ImageJ-Linux64 which should not and obviously  does not exist within your Fiji folder!

Comment: [Fiji](http://imagej.net/Install_Fiji_on_Linux). This link I have used to download the linux version of fiji which contain the ImageJ-linux64  not Fiji-linux or something else. So can anybody tell me where I am wrong and again how to add fiji as a default image viewer in simpleITK. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the extension of the file with the system variable SITK_SHOW_EXTENSION and try to provide the command to the visualisation software with SITK_SHOW_COMMAND.
In my .bash_profile I have:

```
export SITK_SHOW_COMMAND='itksnap'
```

Other instructions can be obtained with ?sitk.Show() .

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "%F" to "%f".  It is case sensitive.  Or actually, you can just leave it off.  If there is no "%f" it will just put the file name at the end of the command line.

Also, you can use SimpleITK/ImageJ to view MHA files.  SimpleITK actually writes out a Nifti file by default when Show is called, regardless of the input image.